# PHP MYSQL multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having major headaches trying to create a multidimensional array from two separate MySQL selects.... I've been searching here and Google all day and have to finally admit defeat and ask for some help (I'm a newbie as well which doesn't help!!!).

I have two tables, one which contains a single row result per id and another which can contain several rows for an id. What I'm trying to do is combine the two into a multidimensional array.

My code (poor as it may be) looks like this:

```
require 'php/phpConnection.php';

$sqlString1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM supportstaff_section1_a");

$firstArray = array();
$secondArray = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlString1)) {
    $applicantID = $r['id'];
    $sqlString2 = mysql_query("SELECT educationalname FROM supportstaff_section5 WHERE id = '$applicantID'");

    while ($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlString2)) {
        $secondArray[] = $x;
    }
    $firstArray[] = $r + $secondArray;
    $secondArray  = array();
}
print json_encode($firstArray);
mysql_close($con);
```

The result is this:

```
[{"id":"8m8wwy","0":{"educationalname":"GCSE - English"},"1":{"educationalname":"GCSE - Maths"}},{"id":"wiL7Bn"},{"id":"zAw6M1"}]
```

But I **think** it needs to look something like this:

```
[{"id":"8m8wwy","Array2":"[{"educationalname":"GCSE - English"},{"educationalname":"GCSE - Maths"}]"},{"id":"wiL7Bn"},{"id":"zAw6M1"}]
```

Anyway, how can I insert my second SQL Select into my first SQL Select for each ID.

Thanks for any advice/help.

**EDIT**

Taken from W3Schools.com:

```
Array
(
    [Griffin] => Array
    (
    [0] => Peter
    [1] => Lois
    [2] => Megan
    )
[Quagmire] => Array
    (
    [0] => Glenn
    )
[Brown] => Array
    (
    [0] => Cleveland
    [1] => Loretta
    [2] => Junior
    )
)
```

I'm trying to make it work like the above.

Comment: What's the difference between the first and the second - can you explain it?

Comment: The difference between the first and second tables would be that the first will only ever contain a single row of results per ID... for example ID, First Name, Second Name etc. The second table can contain multiple rows per ID... for example: ID-A, Exam Result 1 Some Center A, ID-A Exam Result 2 Some Center B, ID-A Exam Result 3 Some Center C etc

Comment: I think what you want to do is an SQL join. Btw, something relevant for the future: [Don't use `mysql_` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: A join would work but I dont want to use a join as I thought a multidimensional array would be better. I wouldn't end up with repeated results from table one which are not needed more than once. Thanks for the tip about mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get a little creative here. Something like the following would work as a join AND with multi-dimensional data:

```
<?php
  require 'php/phpConnection.php';

  // ======================================================================
  // Create a join query (way faster than several separate ones!)
  $sqlquery =
    "SELECT SSSA.id, SSS5.educationalname" .
    " FROM supportstaff_section1_a SSSA" .
      " LEFT OUTER JOIN supportstaff_section5 SSS5 ON SSS5.id = SSSA.ID";


  // ======================================================================
  // Run the query and get our results
  $resultarray = array();
  if ($resource = mysql_query($sqlquery)) {
    while ($curarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
      // Create an array, if it doesn't exist
      if (!isset($resultarray[$curarray["id"]]))
        $resultarray[$curarray["id"]] = array();

      // Add to the array, if not null
      $curstring = (string) $curarray["educationalname"];
      if ($curstring != "")
        $resultarray[$curarray["id"]][] = $curstring;
    }
    mysql_free_result($resource);
  }


  // ======================================================================
  // Convert from a keyed array to a standard indexed array (0, 1, 2, etc.)
  $finalarray = array();
  foreach ($resultarray as $id => & $data) {
    // Start with just ID
    $newarray = array(
      "id" => $id
    );

    // Get the data, if we have any
    if (count($data))
      $newarray["educationalnames"] = & $data;

    // Add to our final array and clear the newarray
    $finalarray[] = & $newarray;
    unset($newarray);
  }


  // ======================================================================
  // Get the JSON of our result
  $jsonresult = json_encode($finalarray);


  // ======================================================================
  // Echo it to test
  echo $jsonresult;


  // ======================================================================
  // Close the database
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And the resulting $jsondata would look like this (but not so unravelled of course):

```
[
  {
    "id": "8m8wwy",
    "educationalnames": ["GCSE - English", "GCSE - Maths"]
  },
  {
    "id": "wiL7Bn"
  },
  {
    "id": "zAw6M1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark... it almost works. If I run the query in PHPMyadmin I get: 
    8m8wwy GCSE - English
    8m8wwy GCSE - Maths
    wiL7Bn NULL
    zAw6M1 NULL
Which is correct but in a browser I only get: [{"id":"id","educationalnames":["GCSE - English","GCSE - Maths"]}] So its sort of working but not returning all results or the correct id.

Comment: Actually, with your edit, it looks like you don't even want to convert the formatting as I have shown, so I would cut out the whole `// Convert from keyed ...`
section and just do the `$jsonresult = json_encode($resultarray);` instead.

Comment: @user1399098 - Nevermind, I found the problem. Fixing in the original! Oops!

Comment: Its this: $jsonresult = json_encode($resultarray); which returns [{"id":"id","educationalnames":["GCSE - English","GCSE - Maths"]}]

Comment: @user1399098 - Can you try the updated version? Also, should I update this to give the EDITED version you were asking for?

Comment: Now it works exactly how I wanted, now all I need to work out is how to get at the data but that'll be some fun for later tonight :).... Thanky ou so much.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for all the comments... it really helped me out.

Comment: That's actually how I code everything, since it helps anybody out looking at the code to know what it's supposed to do. Glad it helped you out!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25027/discussion-between-user1399098-and-mark-ormston)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ID from the first Array, you can check for keys / values with this ID in the second Array.

If you want to get the key you should use

```
array_key_exists($string)
```

And if you want to get the value you should use

```
in_array($string)
```

You can use a foreach loop to execute this functions!